# Using r to Insert Records into a Database using apply

Tags: r, insert, teradata, apply

I have a table i wish to insert records into in a `Teradata` environment using R
I have connected to the the DB and created my Table using JDBC
From reading the documentation there doesn't appear to be an easy way to insert records into the system except to create your own manual insert statements. I am trying to do this by creating a vectorized approach using apply (or anything similar)

Below is my code but I'm clearly not using apply correctly. Can anyone help?

```
s <- seq(1:1000)
str_update_table <- sprintf("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", s) 

# Set Up the Connections
myconn <- dbConnect(drv,service, username, password)

# Attempt to run each of the 1000 sql statements
apply(str_update_table,2,dbSendUpdate,myconn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not got the infrastructure to test, but you pass a vector to apply where apply expects an array. With your vector `str_update_table` the `2` in apply does not make much sense.

Try `Map` like in

```
Map(function(x) dbSendUpdate(myconn, x), str_update_table)
```

(untested)

Comment: Hi @Bernhard. i was hoping we could use purrr for this so thank for for suggesting it. It works perfectly. Sorry i had a typo originally

Comment: I am not familiar with `purrr` but simple tasks like this usually work well without additional packages. Glad, it worked for you.